# selecting the nth highest marks

Tags: sql-server-2005, greatest-n-per-group

I've a table:

```
create table marks(stdName nvarchar(30), marks float)
insert into marks
select 'std1', 98
union all select 'std2', 96
union all select 'std3', 95
union all select 'std4', 97
union all select 'std5', 93
```

I want to create stored procedure to select the row with **nth highest marks** as given input parameter.suppose if the input parameter is 3, it should display 'std2', 96 or if
input parameter is 5, it should display 'std5', 93.

Comment: Can you explain _"'th' highest marks"_? I don't understand the rule for your desired result.

Comment: th means first, second, third, fourth, fifth, sixth ... please look at the last sentence I provided as my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [cte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) with [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function:

```
WITH cte AS(
    SELECT  stdName
    ,       marks
    ,       ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY marks DESC)As MarkRank
    from marks
)
SELECT stdName, marks
FROM cte
WHERE MarkRank = @rank
```

Comment: thank you Tim Schmelter for the reply. will U plz explain me the line "ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY marks DESC)As MarkRank"

Comment: when I run the code I got an error 'Must declare the scalar variable "@rank" ' & how to write stored procedure of this CTE

Answer (score -1):

I've solved this problem. thanks to tim for his help. I was bit confused with the stored procedure.

```
create procedure showmarks
(@rank int)
as
    begin

WITH cte AS(
    SELECT  stdName
    ,       marks
    ,       ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY marks DESC)As MarkRank
    from marks
)
SELECT stdName, marks
FROM cte
WHERE MarkRank = @rank
end
```

Comment: The appropriate way would be to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) and/or upvote answers instead of posting the same as own answer.

Comment: @ Tim Schmelter, no man I asked for the way of writing stored procedure and  U leave that. and ur answer made me confused. I've commented on ur reply too. any way thank you for the reply.